# How to fill XFA form using iText?

Tags: xml, pdf, itext, xfa

Code:

```
using (FileStream pdf = new FileStream("C:/test.pdf", FileMode.Open))
using (FileStream xml = new FileStream("C:/test.xml", FileMode.Open))
using (FileStream filledPdf = new FileStream("C:/test_f.pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
   PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
   PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, filledPdf);

   stamper.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm(xml);
   stamper.Close();
   pdfReader.Close();
}
```

This code throws no exception and everything seems to be ok, but if I open filled pdf, Adobe Reader says something like that:

> This document enabled extended features. This document was changed since it was created and using extended features isn't possible anymore.

Some fields are filled properly, but I can't edit it. Some fields are empty. 
If I choose xml manually by clicking 'Import data' from Adobe Reader, form is filled properly, so I guess there is no error in xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not creating the `PdfStamper` object correctly. Use:

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, filledPdf, '\0', true)
```

In your code, you are not using `PdfStamper` in append mode. This means that iText will reorganize the different objects in your PDF. Usually that isn't a problem.

However: your PDF is Reader-enabled, which means that your PDF is digitally signed using a private key owned by Adobe. By reorganizing the objects inside the PDF, that signature is broken. This is made clear by the message you already mentioned:

> This document enabled extended features. This document was changed
>   since it was created and using extended features isn't possible
>   anymore.

You changed the document in a way that isn't allowed (see section 8.7 of my [book](http://itextpdf.com/book) entitled "Preserving the usage rights of Reader-enabled forms").

To avoid breaking the signature, you need to use `PdfStamper` in append mode. Instead of reorganizing the original content, iText will now keep the original file intact and append new content after the end of the original file.