# How to use PdfStamper for Itext c#

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I need help:

I have the same problem as here:
[How to fill XFA form using iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629498/how-to-fill-xfa-form-using-itext)

"This document enabled extended features. This document was changed since it was created and using extended features isn't possible anymore."

I do not know how to use PdfStamper.
Here is my code. Can you pls tell me how to use PdfStamper in my code.

Output PDF document is now read-only (I am not able to write in Fields), will PdfStamper also solve the read-only problem?

```
string DEST = "C:\\PDF\\code_empty1.pdf";
string SRC = "C:\\PDF\\code_empty.pdf";
string XML = "C:\\PDF\\code_emptyKopie.xml";


ManipulatePdfFill(DEST);

void ManipulatePdfFill(string dest)

{
    PdfDocument pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(dest));
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfdoc, true);

    XfaForm xfa = form.GetXfaForm();

    // Method fills this object with XFA data under datasets/data.
    xfa.FillXfaForm(new FileStream(XML, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    xfa.Write(pdfdoc);

    pdfdoc.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you attach the PDF/XML files that you are using to run your code?

Comment: `PdfStamper` is a class used in iText 5 and earlier. Its functionality is a special case of the `PdfDocument` class in iText 7 when generated with both a `PdfReader` and a `PdfWriter` argument. The _append mode_ mentioned in that `PdfStamper` answer can be set by using an additional `StampingProperties` constructor argument with `useAppendMode` selected. Nonetheless, Adobe Acrobat is very picky and attempts to recognize and reject changes by other software.

Comment: I am not able to attach PDF (sensible data is in PDF)